# Different ROMs need different GApps?

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-apps

I am currently using  ParanoidAndroid rom and I am switching to Cyanogen 10 on my Galaxy Nexus.

Do I need to download/install a new Gapps .zip file?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the actual android version of the ROM you flashed. it the ParanoidROM and Cyanogenmod ROM are both Android 4.2 then you don't need a new set of gapps, if there aren't then if might just be safe to get a new set of gapps

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to download gapps from here: [GApps](http://goo.im/gapps).

Just choose the correct version of Cyanogen mod that you have.

Note: Cyanogenmod 10 has another gapps then Cyanogenmod 10.1.